# How to detect unknown phone number in call logs (android provider)

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, calllog

I would like to detect the unknown phone number in my call logs list.

An unknown number on the phone is either `-1` or `-2`.

My question is *how to detect this type of call*?.

I try to detect with :

```
number = Integer.parseInt(number);
if(number < 0){

}
```

but it is not working.

Comment: First, the parameter for parseInt is a string. Is variable number a string type?

Comment: Chances are the suspect code is before the IF statement. Perhaps you should provide more code for us to help.

Comment: Please improve your acceptance rating - member for 1 year/1month, asked 14 questions ...

Comment: Try my instructions below and tell us what you get?  Ask if you have any questions on debugging or adding the log statements.

Comment: @CodeDroid I beg your pardon - we're not slaves to you!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

1) Log everything.

Put

```
  Log.debug("ClassName", "number = " +number);
```

2)  number = Integer.parseInt(number);
    does not look quite right.
    try

assuming incomingPhoneNumber is defined as a String.

```
   String incomingPhoneNumber;

   try{

     int phoneNumber = Integer.parseInt(incomingPhoneNumber);

    }catch (Exception e) {
      Log.debug("ClassName", "error = "+e.getMessage());
      }
```

in eclipse you need to goto window -->Show View --> Logcat to and examine the log message but you should also just set breakpoints and run in debug mode. Step one line at a time.

Tell us if you get a negative number for the incoming call.

3) Place breakpoints at the very beginning and run in debug mode. Tell us what you get.

4) Communicate with the user questions.  People are trying to help but you need to answer our questions for us to help you.  For example we do need to see the definition for number to know if
  the code is going to work.